# Flexbox divs overlap and responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make some elements overlap and staggered using flexbox, but I also need it responsive to stack when on mobile. I am new to flexbox and want to see if I can get some help making this responsive. Below is my html and css. As you can see when you run the snippet, it is not how I want it to look. This is my codepen and that is the desktop layout I would like, then I would like the divs to stack as it gets to mobile: https://codepen.io/ascarb1/full/zWZVRw/

Any help is really appreciated.

```css
body {
  max-width: 1600px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.home-story-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10em auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: left;
  float: none;
}

.home-story-container .home-story-text-block {
  height: 373px;
  width: 618px;
  background: #ddd;
  align-self: flex-start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: 15em;
}

.home-story-container .home-story-text-block .home-story-text-content {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 4em 0 0 4em;
}

.home-story-container .home-story-image-block {
  width: 640px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 14em;
  margin-top: -23em;
}

.home-story-container .home-story-video-block {
  width: auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: 21em;
  margin-top: -10em;
}

.home-story-container .home-story-quote-block {
  align-self: flex-end;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 16em;
  margin-top: -9.5em;
  width: 413px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="home-story-container">
    <div class="home-story-text-block">
      <div class="home-story-text-content">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, malesuada quisque sit consectetuer adipiscing odit, sed tortor leo nunc, a vel erat ultricies.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-story-image-block"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x373"></div>
    <div class="home-story-video-block"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SkgTxQm9DWM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
    <div class="home-story-quote-block">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I am struggling making these responsive, the flex-end divs break all the way to the left as the screen size changes.

Comment: I think the div that must be a flex box is `home-story-text-content` that contains `div` and `h1` and `p` .

Comment: why would that be? The content is within the div's I am wanting to make responsive. The main struggle is the flex-end elements, they instantly move and overlap too much when the screen size changes.

Comment: Could you create a snippet? It will be easier for every one who tries to help you

Comment: Created a snippet, and linked to a codepen that shows the desktop layout. Also updated the question with what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: As I see both of the `flex-end` elements are working truly, But they are not at the end because of their margin. And the problem i found is that in responsive design you must to not have any element with the `width` property larger than mobile screen. It is better your element has dynamic `width` or less than `300px` (sorry for my bad english)